# Event In GridView, Postback And Databinding Loss

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I have a simple gridview in a user control.

This gridview is binding to a List of object type `Foo` that just has a simple string property:

```
public class Foo
{
      public string MyProperty {get; set;
}
```

To do the databinding, I have the following code. The `MyFoos` property is the collection I am binding to. I set this property in the page_load of the page hosting the user control. `gridMyFoos` is the id of the gridview in question.

```
public List<Foo> MyFoos {get; set;}

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if (!Page.IsPostBack)
          {
            if (MyFoos != null)
            {
                PopulateGrid();
            }
         }
    }

private void PopulateGrid()
{
        gridMyFoos.DataSource = MyFoos;
        gridMyFoos.DataBind();
```

}

I have Edit and Delete buttons in the `gridMyFoos` using the regular old way with `EditItemTemplate`.

Here is the problem. If I take out the `!Page.IsPostBack` I see records, however the `RowCommand` events will not fire. If I keep it in there, I don't see any records. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RowUpdating event:

```
GridView gv  = ((GridView)sender);
GridViewRow row = gv.Rows[e.RowIndex];
```

and the RowEditing event put this:

```
gvName.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
```

Comment: unfortunately, these events are also not triggered if I take out the postback check.

Comment: did you call the method populatedGrid after code for edit ?.Because you need to do

Comment: Yes I call it after each event. breakpoints aren't hit on it.

Comment: did you check the gridview events in the html? ,maybe something is wrong

Comment: maybe he forgot to add the events names in the gridview design? that's why it's always better to post the markup when asking questions.